# Восстановление введенного текста( неопределенное количество полей) при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, dom, кэширование

Есть текстовый инпут:

```html
<div>

  <textarea placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' rows='10' cols='45'></textarea>

  <input type='text' placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' style="width:95%; height: 40px;">
  <textarea placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' rows='10' cols='45'></textarea>
</div>
```

Надо чтобы он не сбрасывался при перезагрузке страницы. В блоке `div` может быть произвольное количество полей ввода.
Минимум кода.

Comment: Если текста не очень много, используйте локальное хранилище. Иначе - отправляйте на сервер и извлекайте по ID.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage на jQuery:

```js
$('textarea, input', 'div').each(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem(id)) {
    this.value = localStorage.getItem(id);
  }
  $(this).on('change input keyup', function() {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem(id, this.value);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea id="t1" placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' rows='10' cols='45'></textarea>
  <input id="t2" type='text' placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' style="width:95%; height: 40px;">
  <textarea id="t3" placeholder='Надо чтобы введенный тут текст не пропадал при перезагрузке страницы' rows='10' cols='45'></textarea>
</div>
```

Ограничение LocalStorage - 5MB на хост.

И по-хорошему сюда можно ещё добавить debounce на сохранение.